# Alternative to The Elements of Statistical Learning: Data Mining, Inference, and Prediction

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, references

I am taking a class in statistics which uses The Elements of Statistical Learning: Data Mining, Inference, and Prediction as a textbook. However, I find this book very terse.

Could anyone please recommend a book which has similar topic coverage but contains more examples and detailed explanations and does not omit mathematical derivations.

P.S. I found Introduction to Statistical Learning as a good introductory level book. It was easy to read and provided a good overview of ML methods. However, I would like to see more rigorous explanations and mathematical derivations of the methods.

Comment: Is your question really different from [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12386/machine-learning-cookbook-reference-card-cheatsheet), [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/244309/book-for-machine-learning) or [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/35535/a-good-machine-learning-book)? Or is it a duplicate of one of those (or yet another one)?

Comment: You can checkout Christopher Bishop's ML book